# Processing SMTP bounces with .net

Tags: asp.net, smtp, email-bounces

Am looking for examples specific to .net/mvc and servers native WinServer08 where problem being addressed is processing a bounced smtp msg so as to bind to an estore transaction and updating account/profile properties.

Reading the *[related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204910/tool-for-parsing-smtp-logs-that-finds-bounces)* i find an interesting reference to **[VERP]**[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path#Software_that_supports_VERP). Under the heading '**Software that supports VERP** i find that IIS is not on the list. Does that mean i need to find a library to integrate into my store's assembly?

What resources do I have to pull together to make sure that the webapp is informed when mail bounces? fwiw - i'm working with a very low volume site.

Comment: Related/duplicate (with very few answers, unfortunately): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092360/how-to-automate-handling-of-bounce-mails-in-a-windows-net-environment

Comment: Seems bizarre there isn't more traffic on a question like this. Is it just a matter of the task being done some much better on non-win servers that there's no need? The price point of the suggested utilities sure makes one think there's lots of room on the lower end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be too simplistic of an answer, but couldn't you just set up a mailbox, send from that mailbox, use a .NET console app to check the mailbox periodically for bounce emails, and then update your customer account accordingly? I mean, that's free... right?

Comment: It sure seems like it should be that simple but from the looks of other discussions there are 'bounced messages' and then there are 'bounced messages' which (apparently) can be confused with 'bounced messages'. Problem seems to boil down to accurately equating a bounced message with truly bad/invalid address. Still looking for examples specific to the MS/.net stack. thx