# How to get Bounced Emails in PHP on ubuntu3.9 Server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, email-bounces

```
<code> <pre>
$headers        =       "From: $from_name <$from_email>\r\n"; 
$headers        .=      "Reply-To: $bounce_email\r\n";
$headers        .=      "Return-Path: $bounce_email\r\n";
$headers        .=      "Return-Receipt-To: $bounce_email\r\n";
$headers        .=      "X-Mailer: PHP\r\n";
$headers        .=      'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers        .=  'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'. "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); </pre>
</code>
```

I have spent a lot of time on Google  but not able to find it, can any one tell me solution of this or find any error in above code.

Looking forward to your quick responses.

Comment: What is the issue? What are you trying to achieve? What is the purpose of this code? Currently your question looks like - 'I have a problem please help'. Maybe you should explain a bit more?

Comment: Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571806/bounced-mail-handling-in-php-any-up-to-date-solutions that question is more than enough to figure out the problem IMO

Comment: #AlexKey Question is : I am sending emails to thousands of users using php function mail() with above headers, i have set header for bounced emails too but i am unable to get bounced emails on defined email. So i want to know how to get bounced emails in PHP ? Does this make sense now ?

Comment: I'd suggest you 1) edit your question accrodingly 2) refer to the link i put in my comment, that link has enough information to resolve your problem I believe.