# Get Bounces from php mailer without smtp

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to send emails without using an actual account so this is what I have so far

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->Sender = BOUNCE_EMAIL;
    $mail->setFrom($fromAddress,str_replace("\"", "",$fromName));
    $mail->addAddress($toAddress,$toName);
    $mail->addReplyTo($replyAddress);
    $mail->MessageID = $mailHash;

    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body    = $htmlBody ;
    $mail->AltBody = $textBody;
```

I can send emails but I will never receive a bounced email. Is there something I can do to receive bounces using phpmailer but not to use an account?

Answer (score 0):

Bounces are not especially straightforward to handle through PHP especially if you can't use an inbox - consider reading through the following [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571806/bounced-mail-handling-in-php-any-up-to-date-solutions).

If you were using an inbox you could set the `Return-Path` to the return address.

Might be worth your time to try/look at various php bounce solutions such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer), [PHP-Bounce-Handler](https://github.com/cfortune/PHP-Bounce-Handler), [phpList](http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigBounces.html), etc. I've no experience with them but looking through their solutions may provide some assistance.